# Operations with ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am truly unable to do this (this is not homework):

In $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are ideals $I = (8)$ and $J = (5+5i)$.

> Give a $z \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ with $I + J = (z)$.

$I + J = \{i+j:i \in I, j \in J \}$

> Give a $z \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ with $IJ = (z)$.

$IJ = \{xij: i \in I, j \in J, x \in \mathbb{Z}[i]\}$

> Give a $z \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ with $I \cap J = (z)$.

$I \cap J = \{x: x \in I \wedge x \in J \}$.

Calculate gcd:
$\\8=(1-i)(5+5i)-2\\
(5+5i)=(3+3i)(2)+(-1-i)\\
2=(-1+i)(-1-i)$

Thus, $\gcd(8,5+5i)=(-1-i)$.

Comment: Start by writing the definitions of $I+J,IJ$ and $I\cap J$. Expressing them in set builder notation and massaging that should help.

Comment: Do you know that $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain? In other words that the concepts of gcd, lcm and Bezout's identity work there just as they do in the integers. Now, what would happen here, if we were talking about ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$ instead? Generalize!

Comment: I wouldn't know how to apply these.

Comment: what to do now!